# How to emulate a mouse-click and similar degree of interactivity by an Office Add-In?

Tags: excel, visual-studio, ms-office, vsto

This will be my first Add-In. Please bear with me.

The goal of my add-in application is to replicate a very tedious, repetitive work by a user. She tells me that she initiates her task by clicking in some sort of combo box or drop-down menu and typing several digits, followed by a click on the "Ok" button.

Question No. 1: What is the official name of that contraption (the one in mustard color) and how is it coded into an Excel cell?

[image]

I gather than Add-Ins are coded using something called "Object Model"? I have seen about 4 lines of such code.

Is there a statement like this?

```
ClickOnCell("E32");
```

Comment: You need to become familiar with the "Object Model"

Comment: She should be using `Alt+{Down}, e, {type value}, {Enter}`. But I think you want to start your automation after she filters, don't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the lack of responses, both here and in 2 Microsoft forums, I have decided that the answer is:

```
    There is no way
```

Then again, with only 13 people *reading* the question, the chances of one of them knowing the answer are very low.

Answer (score 1):

That contraption is a filter.

If she always types the same number into the filter search then you could store the filter as a custom view in the sheet.

Comment: The number varies. I guess I could put up some sort of WPF dialog box to retrieve it and next perform a search (i.e. emulate the filter's job).